# find command behaviour when matching names without quotes

Tags: linux, bash, find

I was looking for differences in the `find` command with double quotes and without quotes.

I found something odd. I have two files:

- `xWrapper.java`
- `YWrapper.java`

and some in the pattern `*Wrapper.java`.

I ran

```
find . -name *Wrapper.java
```

which should return the first file that matches the pattern, because the command expands as

```
find . -name xWrapper.java yWrapper.java ..
```

But as a result, I got the all the files of that form. Why did it return *all* the files matching that pattern?

Comment: You should have actually gotten an error about "paths must precede expression" or "unknown primary or operator" depending on the version of find you use (GNU vs BSD).

Answer (score 7):

If anything you should get an error message if you are in the same catalog:

```
~$ mkdir test
~$ cd test
~/test$ touch {X,Y}Wrapper.java
~/test$ find . -name *Wrapper.java
find: paths must precede expression: YWrapper.java
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

since the asterisk will be expanded, and `-name` only takes a single argument.

If you come from a location where the asterisk is not expanded:

```
~/test$ cd ..
~$ find test -name *Wrapper.java
test/XWrapper.java
test/YWrapper.java
```

Since the asterisk is now *not* expanded (as long as it does not match anything in the current directory), `find` sees it "as is", and uses it as a wildcard.

You should wrap the `-name` argument in single quotes to avoid such context dependent behavior:

```
~/test$ find . -name '*Wrapper.java'
./XWrapper.java
./YWrapper.java
```

Comment: Double quotes would work here as well.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, correct. One can also escape the asterisk with backslash for the same effect. I thought of my formulation after I posted, and since single quotes can help against other possible string issues (escape characters specific to the shell), I let it stand as recommended practice, since it in this case concerns a string that most definitely is meant to be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `or` function because `-name` is a single string argument.

```
find . \( -name "xWrapper.java" -o -name "yWrapper.java" \)
```

Or you can use regex to find the file with

```
find . -regex '.*\(x\|y\)Wrapper.java'
```

Comment: This was not really the question. It was about why `find` behaved as it did with unquoted asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[max@localhost ~]$ touch 1file
[max@localhost ~]$ touch 2file
[max@localhost ~]$ touch 3file
[max@localhost ~]$ touch 4file
[max@localhost ~]$ touch 5file
[max@localhost ~]$ find -name "*file"
./4file
./2file
./Desktop/new file
./Desktop/DESKTOP/new file
./.bash_profile
./#file
./3file
./1file
./5file
./file
./file/file
```

This will match all the filename ending with `file`

```
[max@localhost ~]$ find . -name 'file*'
./file1
./.gconf/apps/file-roller
./Downloads/opera-10.60-6386.i386.linux/share/opera/unite/fileSharing.ua
./Downloads/opera-10.60-6386.i386.linux/share/opera/defaults/filehandler.ini
./Downloads/opera-10.60-6386.i386.linux/share/opera/styles/images/file.png
./.gnome2/file-roller
./.local/share/Trash/files
./file
./file/file2
./file/file
```

This will match all the filename staring with `file`

```
[max@localhost ~]$ find -name "1file"
./1file
```

This will match only filename `1file`

```
[max@localhost ~/avi]$ touch a
[max@localhost ~/avi]$ touch b
[max@localhost ~/avi]$ touch "a b"
[max@localhost ~/avi]$ ll
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max 0 Jul 31 13:49 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max 0 Jul 31 13:49 a b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max 0 Jul 31 13:49 b
[max@localhost ~/avi]$ find . -name a
./a
[max@localhost ~/avi]$ find . -name b
./b
[max@localhost ~/avi]$ find . -name a b
find: paths must precede expression: b
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] 
[expression]
[max@localhost ~/avi]$ find . -name "a b"
./a b
```

(" or ') symbol will useful when there is a space in between filename like "a b"

Comment: This was not really the question. He wonders why his specific example behaved as it did in the interplay of `find` and Bash.